# Node multiple apps in the same folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Is there any problem doing this :

My app structure

> -my_app
> -- node_modules
> -- server1.js (express server running on port 3000)
> -- server2.js (express server running on port 3001)
> -- mymodule.js (exports some database functions)
> -- package.js (express,mysql depentancies etc.)

Those apps will both use `mymodule.js` [`const module = require('./mymodule)`] and will call functions from inside(database requests)
Now if i spawn 2 process `node server1.js` and `node server2.js`
is there going to be any conflict/access problem for my 2 apps, or any other problem?

Comment: define conflict/access problem in more detail. generally no there won't be any issues if you're just sharing code, if your sharing connections your need to do some tests, especially if your not using a pool

Comment: Just files. Not connections i will handle connection conficts from inside the code. I am just wondering about if there are any problems that they will share the same node_modules folder and lot's of my own .js module files

Comment: will be fine, that's essentially what modules are, shared code/text